# ios - import using openframeworks and use it glview

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, openframeworks, glsles

Just a thought, is it possible to use openframeworks to import some 3d objects then pass it to glview from ios then mess with glsl? 
I am using of_ios_074 at the moment and based on further reading it seems like there are still not yet porting over to Opengles 2.0, that means we cannot use glsl yet right?

Comment: personally I don't have a lot of experience with OpenGL ES2.0 but you should take a peek at [this post](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/index.php?topic=9107.0) and maybe [this version of oF](https://github.com/andreasmuller/openFrameworks/tree/develop-opengles2)

Comment: Hi George. Yup I seen this post. That is why I want to try using ios's glsl. But that might not be as easy too.